# Firebase FCM React project issue - firebase-messaging-sw.js wrong type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im tryin to get Firebase FCM working in my React project(using webpack )

When trying to getToken() using:

```
 messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    console.log('token')
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  });
```

the exception is thrown as follows:

```
browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The scrip 
has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')
```

I understand that this issue is related to the missing service worker file: firebase-messaging-sw.js, which I added to the root of the project but I'm still getting the same error.

Im not sure what im doing wrong here, i've set up vanilla java script project and it works fine ....

Any ideas about this issue ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For those using create-react-app, you can create the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` inside `public` folder and, on `index.js` add:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: `React+Vite` and `Vue+Vite` deployed in vercel or netlify => make a folder `public` in the top root of project , create `firebase-messaging-sw.js` inside the folder, and by following the above method worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using create-react-app. Add firebase-messaging-sw.js to your public folder and rebuild. firebase-messaging-sw.js can be an empty file

Answer (score 7):

If you are using firebase, react and you scaffold with **create react app** things you need to do:

- create (or move) a file in the **public** folder name it firebase-messaging-sw-.js

  - this issue is because the default route is your root folder, but since the scaffolder uses **webpack** you can't put the simple file in your root folder, it got to be placed in your public folder or do some config in your webpack dev server to be able to load that file from a different route
- [register](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useServiceWorker) your service worker and associate that file with firebase
- you can do this in the index file (bootstrap)
- Check that your service worker has been registered in your browser
- for chrome you go to Devtools > Application > ServiceWorker and check yours is register

  - if you have any issue delete you service worker and register it again

(based on @Humble Student answer)

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then(function(registration) {
        firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
    });
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

In order to receive messages, you will need to create a file called `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. See the section [Handle messages when your web app is in the foreground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground) in the Firebase documentation:

> In order to receive the onMessage event, your app must define the Firebase messaging service worker in `firebase-messaging-sw.js`.

Comment: In react, insn't the service handled when calling `import firebase from 'firebase'`? It looks like firebase-messaging-sw.js imports what I already have imported.... Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here was that my project setup didn't 'see' service worker file.

Since i'm using node with express, the firebase-messaging-sw.js had to be place where express is picking up static content. In my case line:

```
server.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'dist')));
```

means that I had to put firebase-messaging-sw.js into /dist folder.

Comment: it also worked for me at react with create-react-app tool.

Just placing the sw file in the /public

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem as in the original question, and I have gone through all kinds of solutions without any luck over the past 3 days. I am using ReactJS and Webpack. I've tried to include file called firebase-messaging-sw.js in my root folder, but it does nothing.

Someone, please help, since the firebase notification is a much needed feature in the project I am developing...

EDIT.

I managed to solve the registration problem by installing a webpack plugin called sw-precache-webpack-plugin. This plugin autogenerates a service-worker file for you into your build directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: My bad, I just want this question to get attention to get a possible solution. Should I remove the answer and add it as a comment or something?

Comment: This post should be removed, yes. Concerning the attention: The best way to do that would be [setting a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), but that requires 75 reputation. Posts like this and comments are unlikely to help in this regard.

Comment: Put service worker in folder where static content is served?