# Firebase FCM with ReactJS and Webpack not working: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging

Related question with pretty much the same issue: [Firebase FCM React project issue - firebase-messaging-sw.js wrong type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612026/firebase-fcm-react-project-issue-firebase-messaging-sw-js-wrong-type)

Answers in this question or any other have not worked for me, below is a screenshot of the project tree with firebase-messaging-sw.js file in it, since adding it has been a occuring suggestion to fix this issue.

[image: firebase-messaging-sw]

I would like to know if I am just doing it wrong or why I am not able to register the sw for the firebase to use.

Original error from developer tools console: 
"Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script."

Comment: 2 condition should be passed for SW installation, **1st** site should be served with https/localhost **2nd** you should include `service_worker.js`. have you include `service_worker.js`..?

Comment: How do you get an SSL certificate on a localhost? And what do you mean with including service_worker.js? Like is it some library I have to download or what?

Comment: sorry for this https/localhost ...it is `https or localhost `...! your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` will help to get FCM push notifications, you have to include `service-worker.js` file separately.

Comment: see this documention https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web

Comment: this is details explanation for sw.js https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/

Comment: I finally managed to register the service worker, I needed to install a plugin that generates the service worker file into my build output, since that is where the file is looked for during runtime.

Comment: Now I have  a different problem, I don't know ho to modify the content of the generated sw file. I only need the file to detect notifications coming from by backend send with firebase cloud messaging. I don't actually need to cache all of my source code, just the firebase stuff. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @MirkoFlyktman I am facing same issue , trying to add sw file on webpack for firebase notification , I managed to add sw file using webpack plugin but i want to add more functions to that file like setBackgroundMessageHandler() but i am not able to do that. even i am not able to see icon in my notification , please tell me the way of using service worker file with firebase listeners .

Comment: I actually solved my firebase issues, and already had another question opened in SO for another issue that also helps with this one. I can link it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aswer to this issue, here is another post by me which I also managed to solve myself. [FirebaseError - messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657131/firebaseerror-messaging-failed-serviceworker-registration)

So basically using a very specific version of webpack-dev-server, adding a sw file that can have any name, and registering that file as a service worker for fireabse to use in my firebase messaging initialization file, I managed to get firebase cloud messaging working with webpack. The version of webpack-dev-server is 2.11.0.

Hope this helps anyone with this issue.