# Failed to register service worker with unsupported MIME type

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to integrate our app (which is running based on Javascript, no react, no angular) with firebase to support push notifications on our devices. But we are getting "unsupported MIME type" when we are trying to register the service worker.

Below is the code.

**index.html:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

var config = {
      messagingSenderId: "1234567890"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
.then(function (registration) {
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
        console.log('Notification Permission granted');
        messaging.getToken().then(function (currentToken) {
            console.log('Firebase token : ', currentToken);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Push Message is disallowed');
    });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log('Message received. ', payload);
     });
 }, err => {
        console.log('Error while registering', err);
 })
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js:**

```
if('function' === typeof importScripts) {
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-app.js')
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-messaging.js')

    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "sdsd",
        authDomain: "sdsd",
        databaseURL: "sdsd",
        projectId: "sdsd",
        storageBucket: "sdsd",
        messagingSenderId: "1234567890",
        appId: "sdsd"
    };

    var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
        return self.registration.showNotification("", {body: payload.data.status});
    });
}
```

**index.html, firebase-messaging-sw.js, manifest.json all are in same directory.** But index.html is unable to register the service worker and I am getting 'unsupported MIME type' error.

I saw some posts about this error but all those posts are related to react.js as given below.

- [Firebase FCM React project issue - firebase-messaging-sw.js wrong type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612026/firebase-fcm-react-project-issue-firebase-messaging-sw-js-wrong-type)
- [Firebase: change the location of the service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659970/firebase-change-the-location-of-the-service-worker)

But we are not using react.js to place firebase-messaging-sw.js in public directory. Can any one please let me know where to place files firebase-messaging-sw.js and manifest.json, how to refer the file from navigator.serviceWorker.register() in index.html to fix this issue.

Comment: Replace `./firebase-messaging-sw.js` with `firebase-messaging-sw.js`?

Comment: Tried that. It is not working.